# In search of material to learn how to develop UWP apps using Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, uwp

where can I learn to make UWP apps using visual c++.The only resource I've found shows how to make a 'Hello World' app. This is insufficient because I want to make an app that has multiple pages and utilizes custom classes.

Answer (score 1):

To develop UWP apps, the official channel is the official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/

Depending on your requirements, you need to use the appropriate [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/) in your app.

For the specific API, there's specific code sample for your reference. You could get the demos from GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

If you want a complete project to learn how to develop a UWP app. There's an existing open source project [MS-Calculator](https://github.com/Microsoft/calculator). It's UWP app and developed by c++ language.